# How to compile Browser source code for Android 4.0.3

Tags: android

I downloaded the Browser source code from https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser.

I am able to access the hidden and internal package with the help of http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/ tutorial.

I am not able to build the source code for Android 4.0.3. But when compiled for Android 4.0.3 Eclipse shows "This class must implement the inherited abstract method AbsSpinner.layout(int, boolean), but cannot override it since it is not visible from FolderSpinner. Either make the type abstract or make the inherited method visible" error in FolderSpinner class.

Thanks in advance for help.

Regards,
Vibhor

Answer (score 2):

You can only build AOSP apps as part of the whole firmware. They are not designed to be built individually.

Comment: I am able to build the Browser source code for Android 3.2 and the code is running fine on Android 3.2 device. But when I compile the using Android 4.0.3, I get the compile time error. Actually its is a Java compilation error and not able to find the correct reason for the same.

Comment: @vibhor, I tried the steps mentioned in the tutorial for 3.2. I created the classes.dex.dex2.jar file. But inside the jar file i browsed through com/android/internal folder which is empty. I tried many times but facing the same issue.. I am working on windows 7 OS ...Need your help on resolving the issue

Comment: @CommonsWare couldn't I just download the android source and link it?